# ActiveRecord has_many with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to find an object by checking for several of its relations.

```
Loan.joins(:credit_memo_attributes)
    .where(credit_memo_attributes: {name: 'pr2_gtx1_y', value: '2014'})
    .where(credit_memo_attributes: {name: 'pr1_gtx1_y', value: '2013'})
    .where(credit_memo_attributes: {name: 'tx1_y', value: '2014'})
```

Calling `to_sql` on that gives:

```
"SELECT `loans`.* FROM `loans` INNER JOIN `credit_memo_attributes` 
  ON `credit_memo_attributes`.`loan_id` = `loans`.`id` 
  WHERE `credit_memo_attributes`.`name` = 'pr2_gtx1_y' AND `credit_memo_attributes`.`value` = '2014' 
    AND `credit_memo_attributes`.`name` = 'pr1_gtx1_y' AND `credit_memo_attributes`.`value` = '2013' 
    AND `credit_memo_attributes`.`name` = 'tx1_y' AND `credit_memo_attributes`.`value` = '2014'"
```

So, I'm checking for Loans that have credit_memo_attributes with all of those attributes. I know at least 1 of our 20,000 loans meets this criteria, but this query returns an empty set. If I only use 1 of the `where` clauses, it returns several, as I'd expect, but once I add even 1 more, it's empty.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update:

Based on comments I believe you want multiple joins in your criteria. You can do that like this:

```
attr_1 = {name: 'pr2_gtx1_y', value: '2014'}
attr_2 = {name: 'pr1_gtx1_y', value: '2013'}
attr_3 = {name: 'tx1_y', value: '2014'}

Loan.something_cool(attr_1, attr_2, attr_3)

class Loan < ActiveRecord::Base
...
def self.something_cool(attr_1, attr_2, attr_3)
  joins(sanitize_sql(["INNER JOIN credit_memo_attributes AS cma1 ON cma1.loan_id = loans.id AND cma1.name = :name AND cma1.value = :value", attr_1]))
    .joins(sanitize_sql(["INNER JOIN credit_memo_attributes AS cma2 ON cma2.loan_id = loans.id AND cma2.name = :name AND cma2.value = :value", attr_2]))
    .joins(sanitize_sql(["INNER JOIN credit_memo_attributes AS cma3 ON cma3.loan_id = loans.id AND cma3.name = :name AND cma3.value = :value", attr_3]))

end
```

If you look at the SQL generated (that you included in your question, thank you) you'll see that all those conditions are being ANDed together. There are NO rows for which name = 'pr2_gtx1_y' AND name = 'pr1_gtx1_y' (and so forth). So you are getting the result I would expect (no rows).

Comment: No, I do want AND. There are records that meet the criteria where the values exist together, the query is just not put together correctly.

Comment: In a relational database you won't find a record where field_x = "A" AND field_x = "B". Can you give some sample data of rows that you would expect to be returned, but aren't. Also maybe show some other rows that you would expect not to be returned.

Comment: well, i want to check for the relations where there are 3 objects, where field_x = 'foo' for 1, 'bar' for another, and 'baz' for the third. is that possible?

Comment: That's what my code above does. It will give back all rows where field_x = "A" AND field_y = "1" OR field_x = "B" AND field_y = "2" OR field_x = "C" AND field_y = "3". Try it out.

Comment: i see that, but i really do need the AND. all 3 entities need to exist under the same loan in order to be deemed a match.

Comment: Ah, then you need multiple joins. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Any idea if `sanitize_sql` was deprecated? `NoMethodError: undefined method 'sanitize_sql' for main:Object`

Comment: @Dudo. Updated again. sanitize_sql has to be in an ActiveRecord class. :)

Comment: you're a saint. link me to your 'buy me a beer' button

Answer (score 0):

You can put all names and values into array like ids and years and pass those into where clause like this. Active Record will query all the values in the array.

```
Loan.joins(:credit_memo_attributes)
    .where(credit_memo_attributes: {name: ids, value: years})
```

Personally I'm still learning active record, in this concern i don't think active record supports multiple where clauses.

Comment: That will return rows where name = 'pr2_gtx1_y' AND value = '2013'. Is that desirable?

Comment: You need to put all of the ids and values in the array like this ids = ['pr2_gtx1_y', 'pr1_gtx1_y', 'tx1_y'] and years = [ '2014', '2013', '2014'] and add this to where condition, active record will query for all of these.

Comment: Yes, that's what your code would do. I'm asking whether that's a desirable result. You aren't the person who can answer that question, the original poster of the question is. However, I suspect that it's not desirable, which is why I asked.

Comment: what's wrong if i answer to this question? I'm learning rails while working on real problems.

Comment: that is desirable. see comment in the other answer, where i want to check multiple values of the same relation

Comment: I'm sorry for my miscommunication. I meant to indicate that I was trying to ask the poster of the original question whether matching all rows with name = 'pr2_gtx1_y' AND value = '2013' was what was desired. I want to know whether that's the DESIRED result and you aren't the person who knows what the original poster meant.

Comment: so, this query seems to be returning more of an `OR` set... I just pulled up the last result, and checked for one of the values, and it didn't exist.

Comment: @dudo, if such a result is desirable, then this answer is a good way to do that. I'm just surprised that you formulated your question the way you did if this is desirable. However, if you want such records then I recommend accepting this answer.

Comment: @Dudo. Yes this means: if the name is ANY of 'pr2_gx1_y' OR 'pr1_gtx1_y' OR 'tx1_y' AND value is any of '2014' OR '2013' OR '2014' then I want it.

Comment: `Loan.joins(:credit_memo_attributes).where(credit_memo_attributes: {name: %w(pr1_gtx1_y pr2_gtx1_y tx1_y), value: %w(2014 2013)}).last.credit_memo_attributes.where(name: 'pr1_gtx1_y').first
=> nil`

Answer (score 0):

Notice how the `SQL` version is returning your code: it is joining the requirements with an `AND`.

```
"SELECT `loans`.* FROM `loans` INNER JOIN `credit_memo_attributes` 
  ON `credit_memo_attributes`.`loan_id` = `loans`.`id` 
  WHERE `credit_memo_attributes`.`name` = 'pr2_gtx1_y' AND `credit_memo_attributes`.`value` = '2014' 
    AND `credit_memo_attributes`.`name` = 'pr1_gtx1_y' AND `credit_memo_attributes`.`value` = '2013' 
    AND `credit_memo_attributes`.`name` = 'tx1_y' AND `credit_memo_attributes`.`value` = '2014'"
```

Now, this is next to impossible. An `Object.name` can never be all `pr2_gtx1_y`, `pr1_gtx1_y`, and `tx1_y`. Same goes for the `value` attributes.

What you need here is an `OR` as opposed to the `AND`.

To this effect, try to change your query to the following:

```
Loan.joins(:credit_memo_attributes)
  .where(
    "credit_memo_attributes.name = ? and credit_memo_attributes.value = ?
    OR credit_memo_attributes.names = ? and credit_memo_attributes.value = ?
    OR credit_memo_attributes.name = ? and credit_memo_attributes.value = ?",
    'pr2_gtx1_y', '2014',
    'pr1_gtx1_y', '2013',
    'tx1_y', '2014'
  )
```

Comment: but I do want the and... I'm trying to check for 3 objects with different values, that all exist with the same loan_id

Comment: Are you saying you want these, and only these 3 objects? and what is common to them is the `loan_id`?

Comment: almost. i'm saying a loan has 100 credit_memo_attributes. I want to check for 3 of them with specific values (each with a name, and a value).

Comment: Hmm... I still think what you need is an `or`. note however that there is an `and` between each `credit_memo_attributes.name` and `credit_memo_attributes.value`. So, actually, what I have here is a combination of `and` and `or` it is all about the arrangement. Have you tried to use my example above?